# SQL Oracle/Joining two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries which I need to stitch together but I’m not sure how….

This first query pulls through the last three reconciled amounts for any chosen account from a table of accounts, reconciled amounts, periods, and any amount written off (if there was any)

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT   gwod.account_id,
                 EXTRACT(month FROM gwod.charge_period_start) charge_period_month,
                 SUM(gwod.total_due_on_charge) total_due_on_charge,
                 SUM(gwod.amount_written_off) amount_written_off,
                 DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY gwod.account_id 
        ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM 
        gwod.charge_period_start) DESC) rownumber
        FROM     Accounts_report gwod
        WHERE    account_id IN ('')
        GROUP BY gwod.account_id,
                 EXTRACT(month FROM gwod.charge_period_start)
        HAVING   SUM (gwod.total_due_on_charge) <> 0) t1
WHERE  t1.rownumber <=3) 
PIVOT (MAX(charge_period_month) charge_period, 
       MAX(total_due_on_charge) total_due_on_charge, 
       MAX(amount_written_off) amount_written_off 
       FOR rownumber IN (1,2,3))
ORDER BY account_id
```

This query essentially gets me the list of accounts which I’m interested in from some additional tables...

```
WITH Account_Owners AS
          (select gs.account_id, AP.SUPERVISOR
          from Account_Info gs
          Left join ACC_OWNERS AD
          On gs.account_id = AD.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
          Left Join Onwers_Info AP
          On ad.owned_by = AP.ADNAME
          group by account_id, AP.SUPERVISOR
          )

SELECT distinct POLICY_INFO.ACCOUNT_ID, Count (POLICY_INFO.POLICY_NO) As 
Active, a.supervisor
FROM POLICY_INFO
inner join Account_owners a on policy_info.account_id = a.account_id

WHERE Policy_Info.POLICY_STATUS = 'Active'
And policy_info.ACCOUNT_ID is not Null
And a.supervisor in ('David Smith')
GROUP BY Policy_Info.ACCOUNT_ID, a.supervisor
ORDER BY Policy_Info.ACCOUNT_ID
```

What I want to do is have the one query which pulls through the last three reconciled amounts (as per the first query) for all of the accounts of interest (as per the second query); I’m having trouble combining the two however into the single query however…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the first query as another  set in the with clause and `INNER JOIN` it.Also `DISTINCT` might not be required in the final select as you are grouping any way. Try this and let me know if it's correct as it is very difficult for me to visualize data only with the query.

```
 WITH Account_charges AS
    (
    SELECT   *
    FROM     (
    SELECT *
    FROM   (
            SELECT   gwod.account_id,
                     EXTRACT(month FROM gwod.charge_period_start) charge_period_month,
                     SUM(gwod.total_due_on_charge) total_due_on_charge,
                     SUM(gwod.amount_written_off) amount_written_off,
                     DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY gwod.account_id 
                                        ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM gwod.charge_period_start) DESC) rownumber
            FROM     Accounts_report gwod
            WHERE    account_id IN ('')
            GROUP BY gwod.account_id,
                     EXTRACT(month FROM gwod.charge_period_start)
            HAVING   SUM (gwod.total_due_on_charge) <> 0) t1
    WHERE  t1.rownumber <=3) 
    PIVOT (MAX(charge_period_month) charge_period, 
           MAX(total_due_on_charge) total_due_on_charge, 
           MAX(amount_written_off) amount_written_off 
           FOR rownumber IN (1,2,3))
           ),
           Account_Owners AS
              (select gs.account_id, AP.SUPERVISOR
              from Account_Info gs
              Left join ACC_OWNERS AD
              On gs.account_id = AD.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
              Left Join Onwers_Info AP
              On ad.owned_by = AP.ADNAME
              group by account_id, AP.SUPERVISOR
              )
              SELECT distinct POLICY_INFO.ACCOUNT_ID, Count (POLICY_INFO.POLICY_NO) As 
    Active, a.supervisor ,MAX(b.charge_period),MAX(b.total_due_on_charge),MAX(b.amount_written_off) 

--use the proper column names.
    FROM POLICY_INFO
    inner join Account_owners a on policy_info.account_id = a.account_id
    INNER JOIN Account_charges b ON policy_info.account_id = b.account_id

    Where Policy_Info.POLICY_STATUS = 'Active'
    And policy_info.ACCOUNT_ID is not Null
    And a.supervisor in ('David Smith')
    Group by Policy_Info.ACCOUNT_ID, a.supervisor
    order by Policy_Info.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works, but it gives me the same output as the second query, I wasnt sure how to amend so that it gives me the same output as the first query, so the following columns;  Account_ID, 1_Charge_Period, 1_Total_DUE_ON_CHARGE, 1_AMOUNT_WRITTEN_OFF, 2_Charge_Period, 2_Total_DUE_ON_CHARGE, 2_AMOUNT_WRITTEN_OFF,3_Charge_Period, 3_Total_DUE_ON_CHARGE, 3_AMOUNT_WRITTEN_OFF. I need to pull through this info for all of the accounts which are pulled through from the second query. Hope all this makes sense.

Comment: Ok. Then take only the part above `PIVOT`  block in the with clause and add your PIVOT in the final query..?